# ¿Como cargar datos de un formulario a otro con el CODIGO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo Dos Formulario (Form1-Form2) en uno ahi un Datagrid cargado desde la BD.

Quiero que el Form1 se traiga todos los datos del Form2,Pero quiero que con el codigo se traiga todos los datos

Estes es mi formulario principal(Form1) al quiero traer los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el segundo formulario(Form2) el cual quiero tomar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que tengo en el Form2:

```html
  public string codigo;


--------------------------------------------------------
        public string getNumberCodigo()
        {
            this.Close();
            return cododigo;
        }

----------------------------------------------------------

        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            codigo = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            getNumberCodigo();
        }
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

De esta manera llamo al Form2 donde esta el datagridview cargado desde el Form1

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        codigofactura.Text = frm.getNumberFactura();
```

¿Me podrian decir como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo con toda una fila deberás ir pasando todas las filas y mostrarlas como te he puesto abajo

Comment: @Eduardo Reyes me podrias ayudar con esta pregunta

Comment: En tu pregunta no muestras el código de como se agregan los datos al Form1, pero si lo que quieres es agregar a Form2 todos los datos que hay en  Form1, eso es muy sencillo, escribe un código en Form2 similar que el escrito en  Form1, solo cambiando las referencias a los controles, específicamente `dataGridView1`, del Form1 por referencias a los controles del Form2, en el código incluido en tu pregunta, no hay una sola linea que intente hacer nada parecido, te recomiendo revisar como realizar una pregunta en este sitio,[https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822]

Comment: @EduardoReyes quiero pasar los datos del datagrid ubicado en el form2 al form1,..ese es todo el código que tengo con eso solamente me trae el id de la fila que seleccione... pero quisiera que con ese id me trajera todos los datos que tenga ¿hay alguna posibilidad que se pueda hacer?

Comment: Todavía no entiendo lo que pretendes hacer, pues con la modesta experiencia que tengo, puedo asegurar que en tu código no hay nada que pueda transferir los datos del  form2 al form1 (ni al contrario tampoco); con el código que muestras no se puede transferir el id de la fila que seleccionaste, ni todos los datos de todas la celdas de esa fila, ni mucho menos todos los datos del `DataGridView`, es más no encuentro coincidencia entre las imágenes y el código  de tu pregunta. te vuelvo a recomendar revisar como realizar una pregunta en este sitio, [es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string codigo;
    public string cliente;
    public string proveedor;
    Form1 fr = new Form1();

    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        codigo = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cliente = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        proveedor = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        fr.codigoForm1 = codigo;
        fr.clienteForm1 = cliente;
        fr.proveedorForm1 = proveedor;
        fr.Show();

    }
```

Y recibelos de la siguiente:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public string codigoForm1;
    public string clienteForm1;
    public string proveedorForm1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxCodigo.Text = codigoForm1;
        texBoxCliente.Text = clienteForm1;
        texBoxProveedor.Text = proveedorForm1;
    }
```

Comment: disculpa es que no comprendo muy bien tu codigo

Comment: te lo he comentado, mira a ver si lo entiendes mejor

Comment: la parte del codigo que tienes arriba ese lo colocas en el formulario principal o donde esta el datagrid cargado?

Comment: en el formulario que tiene el dataGrid del cual quieres enviar los datos, la parte de abajo en el que los recibe

Comment: aun asi esta confuso tu codigo

Comment: Mira a ver ahora...

Comment: con este codigo ` datoQueEnvias = dataGridViewForm1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();` se supone que mando el CODIGO del registro ¿No deberia ir en el Form2?

Comment: Si, según lo que has subido ahora sería al revés con mi código , mi form2 sería tu form1, con eso envías la primera celda de la fila como habías puesto, para enviar las demás deberás crear una variable para cada una que iguales al dataGrid.currentRow.cells[posición]  y recuperarlas de igual modo

Comment: nada.. no me ha funcionado

Comment: Si quieres cargarlo en un texbox carga la variable que recibes en el texbox.text = datoqueRecibes

Comment: quiero pasar la fila que seleccione al Form1

Comment: mira a ver ahora...

Comment: una pregunta ¿no ahi una manera de cargar los datos solo con el codigo?

Comment: Esa que te he pasado tiene que funcionarte

Answer (score 0):

¿Estas usando entidades? Asi puedes sobrecargar el formulario 1 con un objeto del tipo cliente. Asi:

```
Cliente _cliente = new Cliente();
public Form1(Cliente) : this()
{
  _cliente = Cliente;
}
```

Luego en el formulario dos, le pasas los datos

```
Form2 form = new Fomr2(Cliente);
form2.show();
```

Comment: no ha funcionado